# Create two different pdf using html2pdf at once?

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

I have script like this

```
$this->load->library('html2pdf/html2pdf');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L','A4','en');

$this->html2pdf->WriteHTML($html_1);
$this->html2pdf->Output('PDF1.pdf', 'F');

$this->html2pdf->WriteHTML($html_2);
$this->html2pdf->Output('PDF2.pdf', 'F');
```

for the first PDF2 successfully generate and save on server, but for PDF2 cannot generate properly, just show blank page.

Answer (score 1):

try this ... but this is an example..

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
```

?>

also check see this....

http://html2pdf.fr/en/example

Answer (score 0):

I have try this on two condition, one on **localhost** and one on my **server development**. On localhost, it can success to create two pdf in same time, but not on server development. I do not know, what was lacking in other arrangements or section